# How to install WiFi driver for AsusX550LN when I have no internet connection

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have only WiFi network, so how can I install wireless driver offline?

I'm using Ubuntu version 17.10

Comment: Edited. It’s 17.10 version. Please help.

Comment: My laptop model is ASUS X550ln

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0280]'; rfkill list`? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Windows driver supplied by the laptop manufacturer, the ASUS X550LN has a Ralink RT2860. The Linux driver for this card is called `rt2800pci` and should already be part of the kernel in Ubuntu 17.10: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/rt2800pci.

If the firmware for the card is missing, you may manually download it from http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.1_all.deb and, after moving the .deb to the laptop, install it via `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/linux-firmware_1.169.1_all.deb`. The checksums for the firmware package can be found at the bottom of https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/linux-firmware/download, should you wish to verify them.

After ensuring the firmware is installed, the kernel module for the WiFi card can be manually loaded via `sudo modprobe rt2800pci`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . But I don’t understand anything. Cause i have no knowledge about Ubuntu software installation. Could you please provide me tutorial video or picture so that I can follow the instructions.